# Remove hyphen “-“ from a word and change that word to upper case

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I need to remove hyphen `"-"` from each word and then change that word to upper case. 
I made the below code, But It has no effect on the end result. 
I did not find a way to reflect the changes of each elements on Split Array `arrSP` to the initial array `arr`.

```
Sub Remove_hyphen_and_Change_to_UpperCase()

   Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
   
   Dim rng As Range, arr, arrSP, i As Long, k As Long
   
   Set rng = ws.Range("A2:A" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)      
   
   arr = rng.Value2
  
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
     arrSP = Split(arr(i, 1))
       For k = 0 To UBound(arrSP)
         If arrSP(k) Like "*-*" Then
             arrSP(k) = UCase(CStr(Replace(arrSP(k), "-", "")))
         End If
       Next k
    Next i

   rng.Value = arr
    
End Sub
```

| Current | Expected Result |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8" Water from m-1t and BAD-a then | 8" Water from M1T and BADA then |  |
| Oil service from B-Ad-r , BA-dB | Oil service from BADR , BADB |  |

Comment: Substitute() and upper() would do, in a helper column then paste.special values.

Comment: You can simple add `arr(i, 1) = Join(arrSP)` after `Next k`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write back the result (the modified words) to the array `arr`. The modified words are in the array `arrSP` that you create via `Split` and then modify.

All you have to do is to glue the words of `arrSP` back together to one string and write that back to the element of `arr`. Gluing strings of an array together can be done using the command [`Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/join-function).

```
For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
    arrSP = Split(arr(i, 1))
    For k = 0 To UBound(arrSP)
        If arrSP(k) Like "*-*" Then
            arrSP(k) = UCase(CStr(Replace(arrSP(k), "-", "")))
        End If
    Next k
    ' --> Add the following line to your code
    arr(i, 1) = Join(arrSP, " ")
Next i
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are splitting on spaces, you could also just use some worksheet functions (if on ms365):

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=MAP(A1:A2,LAMBDA(s,LET(x,TEXTSPLIT(s," "),TEXTJOIN(" ",,IF(ISERR(FIND("-",x)),x,UPPER(SUBSTITUTE(x,"-",)))))))
```

Comment: I like this way! It really makes easier with `MS365` formulas! Helps to understand as well!